# ILMerge fails to merge: The assembly 'xxx' was not merged in correctly

Tags: ilmerge

## Problem

Using ILMerge I am trying to merge three assemblies: A, B and C. It fails with the following errormessage. I really need to help to solve this.

> "ILMerge.Merge: The assembly 'B' was not merged in correctly. It is still listed as an external reference in the target assembly."

Assembly A does not reference the other two. B references A. C references A and B.

Command line: ilmerge /v2 /target:library /out:test.dll a.dll b.dll c.dll

## What I have tried

- Use /closed argument. Does not make any difference.
- Different versions of ILMerge, I get the same error with both version 3.0.21.3911 and 2.14.1208.
- Merge A and B first and the merge in C with the A+B merge. This does not produce any error message but the resulting file is broken. It does not run and when I run in through .NET Obfuscator it complains about it.

## Some background

The project is larger than the three assemblies but I have managed to reduce the problem down to these. If I dont include assembly C and only merge A and B the problem goes away.

In the previous version I did not have this problem. Between these two versions there is only non functional changes, like renames (not assembly or namespaces, only classes, methods etc) and reordering of access modifiers (static internal->internal static)

## From the documentation

> A common problem is that after merging some assemblies, you get an error message
> stating that an input assembly was not merged in correctly because it is still listed as an
> external reference in the merged assembly. The most common cause of this problem is
> that one of the input assemblies, B, has an external reference to the incorrectly merged
> assembly, A, and also an external reference to another assembly, C, that itself has an
> external reference to A. Suppose the reference to C is to a method that takes an argument
> whose type is defined in A. Then the type signature of the method call to the method in C
> still refers to the type from A even in the merged assembly. After all, ILMerge cannot go
> and modify the assembly C so that it now depends on the type as it is defined in the
> output assembly after it has been merged!
> The solution is to use the closed option (Section 2.6) to have ILMerge compute the
> transitive closure of the input assemblies to prevent this kind of “dangling reference”. In
> the example, that would result in all three assemblies A, B, and C, being merged. There is
> no way to merge just A and B without there still being an external reference to A.

Comment: Stupid me. There was also assembly renames and I tried to merge the old C. Too many hours wasted but problem solved.